# When BuildSlave has several builders, how d'you know which builder is busy?

Tags: buildbot

When a BuildBot slave has several builders, if the BuildSlave is not IDLE - how can we know which of the builders is the one that keeps the BuildSlave busy?

Answer (score 0):

In the web UI's home page you can see the build logs

[image]

and when selecting a specific build there is detail of builder and worker/slave
[image]

form this you can figure out what's going on